# SSRS - Sum Last 12 items

Tags: reporting-services

I have a Total column and am summing all the values in the row with:

`=Sum(Fields!MyField.Value)`

**How can I sum only the last 12 items?**

This is valid:

`=Last(Fields!MyField.Value)`

I need something like the below...

`=Sum( LastX(Fields!MyField.Value, 12) )`

Comment: what is your data source? If using SQL Server or something, your best bet is to do it there.. use Row number to get the last 12 rows and do a sum(over)

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this result by creating a subquery in your main dataset query. You will just have to have a value that you want to sort on in descending order.

Say you have a table sorted by the price in ASC order. You want to sum the last 12. You just need to flip the sort in the subquery and sum the top 12.

```
SELECT OtherFields, (SELECT TOP 12 Sum(S1.MyField) FROM MyTable S1 ORDER BY S1.MyField DESC) AS BottomTwelveSum
FROM MyMainQueryTable
```

Yes this value will repeat in your dataset, however if you place it correctly in the Table you should be fine, just dont show the value in the details section. This wont add additional rows. Another solution would be using a subreport, however this is much quicker on render time.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm using DAX, and may have to write a new Measure if it can't easily be done within SSRS.

Comment: Please let me know how the attempt goes, as well as if you think this is a valid workaround for your problem

Comment: @TDP Did my solution help at all in solving the problem? Id like to help more if needed